# Navigation bar + windows size

Tags: css

I'm having a hard time trying to figure this out. For example, if you re-size this website's (http://www.noxinnovations.com/) window size until you see the horizontal scroll-bar and then scroll to the right, you'll see that the header's dotted line disappears as well as the color. But sites like facebook or twitter don't have this problem. I was wondering how they do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look their `Html` and `Body` elements do not fill the whole page. (The Firebug extension for Firefox makes this evident.) That isn't normal. What happens though is the element which contains the bar's background ends up being constrained by the body element's size. It is probably just the product of bad design on their part. You shouldn't have that issue if you create a site yourself.